# When should non-work related items, such as being on a Television program be shown on a resumé?

Tags: resume

I have been on a show called All You Need Is Love(The Netherlands) and surprised my girlfriend on that show in a positive way.

Showing the video at my current job made several people say that I should have put that on my resumé even though my function has nothing to do with it.

How should these sorts of projects be listed on your resumé? Or should they be omitted entirely?

Comment: I thought this show ended mid 90's?

Comment: @MichaelGrubey It is still going strong ;)

Comment: No it is not related to acting

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It all depends on the role you are applying for - it is always good to have a resume/CV tailored to what you are applying for rather than the concept of a "general resume" that you send out regardless

So if you are applying for something in the media, perhaps it would be appropriate to show experience within the sector

If you are applying to be an IT developer, completely irrelevant either as a side note or project

Surprising your girlfriend in a positive way on a TV show is not, IMHO only, something that a prospective employer would use a gauge for your enthusiasm/positivity

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Why do you think my current colleages, including the recruiter, told me to place it in my resumé? They told me it would have given it an even further edge over other applicants. Sympathy? Does that differ from company to company? In other words: don't take the risk.

Comment: Are you sure that they weren't joking, like "that's so good, it should go on your resume!"

Comment: Keep in mind that your colleagues might think differently if *they* were the ones doing the recruiting and *they* were responsible if hiring the talent show contestant to manage millions of dollars in data just happened to not work out so well. :)  It's easy to suggest someone do something when you're not responsible for making the decisions.

Comment: If @Ajaxkevi 's resume has an `other activities` section; won't that be a good place to put such achievement?

Comment: @CodingKiwi, they were pretty serious about it. I wouldn't put it on my resumé, but after a few of them told me it would let me stand out. I figured I could ask it here, to hear some opinions.

Answer (score 2):

A resume is read with one question in mind: **Can he do the job?**

If it seems the answer is likely yes, the ensuing process (phone interview, on-site interview, background checks) will try to further establish the primary question, and answer other questions of cultural fit, salary requirements, personal skills, motivation, etc.

I can't imagine a situation where such an item would take you from *not interviewed* to *interviewed* or the other way around, so it really doesn't matter.

However, if I'm reading a resume and having difficulty determining if you can do the job because your resume is cluttered with irrelevant details, I may be put off a bit. And I may question your communication skills a tiny bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your resume should be tailored to the field you are applying for. For example, if you were applying for a sales rep at a shoe store, you would include all the sales experience you have, but omit say, your computer programming experience.

Since I can't imagine being on a reality show like that being applicable for any job, I think you should omit it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say never.  When I'm involved with interviews I'm only concerned with making sure they have the required skills for the job.  Ive never thought we should hire one person over another based on nonwork related items on a resume.  On the other hand you might find someone that disapproves of something you enjoy and pass you up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should have it on the resume. It shows breadth of experience and a unique skill set. It would depend a bit on the content of the acting obviously but I disagree with pretty much everyone here saying that you shouldn't have it. For any good job, the issue isn't "whether you can do the job" but "what makes you stand out from other candidates". Whether you can do the job will be determined at the interview.